# Digester startElement Begin event threw exception

Tags: servlets

while publishing EAR file on WAS7.0 server , I'm getting below exception.

org.apache.commons.digester.Digester startElement Begin event threw exception

I have already included commons-digester.jar file in WEB-INF/lib file but still getting this exception.

Any solutions pls....